# Animate a view in fragment before onDestroy or OnDestroyView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, ondestroy

I have not found anything nearly related.
How do I animate a view before the `onDestroy` and `onDestroyView` `super`s get called?

I've tried with

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fade_out_fast);
    mBackgroundView.setAnimation(fadeOut);
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

This way the super.onDestroyView immediately stop the animation.

Setting a listener to the `fadeOut`, and then calling `MyFrag.super.onDestroyView()` `onAnimationEnd()` didn't work neither, because the super must be called inside the method itself.

How do I go about it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that onDestroyView() is too late for what you are trying to accomplish. Have you tried with you Fragment's onPause() method?

Comment: Yes, thank you.. already tried and still nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've eventually achieved it.

The work is done by a Callback interface and the onBackPressed button from the Activity.

```
public interface UiCallback {
    void update();
}
```

In activity:

```
UiCallback mUiCallbackInstance = new UiCallback() {
    public void update( /* Remove the fragment from stack here */)
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mFragmentInstance.remove(mUiCallbackInstance)
}
```

In fragment:

```
public void remove(UiCallback callback) {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(...);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            callback.update();
        }
    })
    // start animation
}
```